# Nginx - Hide/mask/change value in logs based on Regex match

Tags: nginx, logging, server, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

MY API requires that an email address is used in the path of a request as the identifier of the resource, for example:

```
/api/users/john.smith@company.com
```

Due to concerns with Personally Identifiable Information (PII) being stored in the logs, I'm looking for a method to turn the following log:

```
{ip_address} - - [04/Mar/2021:11:22:22 +0000] "GET /api/users/john.smith@company.com HTTP/1.1" 200 961 "{request_from}" etc.
```

Into something like the following:

```
{ip_address} - - [04/Mar/2021:11:22:22 +0000] "GET /api/users/*email_redacted* HTTP/1.1" 200 961 "{request_from}" etc.
```

I mentioned in the title doing this based on a Regex match as it seems like the obvious way to detect that an email is in the initial log.

I am very new to Nginx so straight-forward concise responses would be really appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access log is controlled by the `access_log` and `log_format` directives (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) for details).

By default, the access log records the value of the `$request` variable, which contains the string you wish to change.

You can use a `map` statement to change the text of the `$request` variable, and use a `log_format` statement to define a new format for the logfile which uses the redacted value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $request $redacted {
    default $request;
    ~^(?<prefix>.*)pattern(?<suffix>.*)$ $prefix*email_redacted*$suffix;
}

log_format redacted '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$redacted" $status $bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log redacted;
```

Replace "pattern" above with a regular expression that matches any legal email address.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you so much for your response; it's people like yourself that run this website! I will have a chance to test this implementation tomorrow, although based on how concise and clear your response is I am confident that it will work. I will mark as correct answer once I have implemented and can confirm 100%. Many thanks again!